# Installed mongrel2 via homebrew, can't find config.sqlite

Tags: web-server, mac-osx, mongrel

I hope this is the right site to ask this, I wasn't sure if here or superuser was more appropriate.

I've installed mongrel2 via Home Brew, which installed it to:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mongrel2/1.7.5
```

However, I am stuck with configuration using `m2sh` as I don't know where to find my sqlite database.

```
$ tree
.
├── INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── bin
│   ├── m2sh
│   └── mongrel2
└── lib
    └── mongrel2
        ├── config_modules
        │   ├── null.so
        │   └── zmq.s o
        └── filters
            └── null.so

5 directories, 8 files
```

`locate config.sqlite` provides no results, and I have no mongrel2 files anywhere in `/etc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no config.sqlite provided because you have to make your own.

See http://mongrel2.org/static/book-finalch4.html#x6-250003.3